# Header used by samsung galaxy android

Tags: android, redirect, header, tablet

I use mobile detection from http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ and that is working ok. Now here is a problem. An android phone should be redirected to a mobile page and a galaxy android, which is a tablet, to the normal page. Now it is going to the mobile page. I think because it is an Android. What can I do to let my php script recognize it and redirect it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the useragent string, tablets in general do not consist "mobile".

You might have been looking for the "android". that might've caused the problem.

I.e. instead of checking for android devices, check for mobile devices.

This is verified on motorola xoom and my galaxy tab